# Save image to database

Tags: laravel

I want to save image name to database but it always save to C:\xampp\tmp\phpAB3A.tmp. btw im not using xampp, im using laragon.How to change the path? i want to save to storage/app/public

```
        'name'=> 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        //'logo' => 'required',


        $imageName = time().'.'.request()->logo->getClientOriginalExtension();
        request()->logo->move(storage_path('app/public'), $imageName);

        Company::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('company.dashboard')->with('Success');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Company::create you have to define the path... Something like:`Company::create([
'path' => torage_path('app/public',$imageName),....]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = $request->all();
$fileName = '';
if ($request->hasFile('logo')) {
    $destinationPath = storage_path('app/public');
    $file = $request->logo;
    $fileName = time() . '.'.$file->clientExtension();
    $file->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
}
$input['logo'] = $fileName;
Company::create($input);
```

Comment: db still save tmp

Comment: echo  `$fileName;` exit; what ever you get store it in db.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using laravel 5.8 and this code worked for me.

**In controller**

```php
<?php

public function store()
{
    // I did like this, because storeLogo method is reusable
    $data = request()->validate([ /* ... */ ]);
    $company = Company::create($data);
    $this->storeLogo($company);

    // but you can do like this
    $data = request()->validate([ /* ... */ ]);
    if (request()->has('logo')) {
        $data['logo'] = request()->logo->store('', 'public');
    }
    $company = Company::create($data);
}

private function storeLogo(Company $company)
{
    if (request()->has('logo')) {
        $company->update([
            'logo' => request()->logo->store('', 'public'),
            // logo file is stored at /storage/app/public/
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: so store name and email is difference than store image eventho they are in the same db?

Comment: I modified code. I wanted to reuse `storeLogo` method, so I wrote code like this. But you can store `Company` in one event.